# Hide repeating divs using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-frontend

```
<div class = "parent">
<div class="swatch-opt-115">
       <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
       <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
          <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">

       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Is it possible to hide the repeating classes - `class="swatch-attribute size"`, and `class="swatch-attribute color"`  using jQuery? So only the first 2 will be visible rest will be hidden. Can someone help?

The `115` in classname `swatch-opt-115` will be dynamic. swatch-attribute color, swatch-attribute size may change but it is sure that they will be repeating. The count may also vary. So we will need to find out the class name of the first child, and then find the repeating classes, and hide them.

Comment: yeah you can add .hide() method by selecting those classes

Comment: So is it fixed that only the two classes you mentioned will be repeated?

Comment: I mean they are not static, just the parent will be static. so it will be some thing like first child, of the parent and then repeating hide

Comment: Add a couple of [nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo-classes to your CSS.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: yes it's possible. What have you researched? What have you tried so far? https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ might help you

Comment: Your markup is invalid. You need the number of `<div>` and `</div>` tags to be equal.

Comment: I am trying like jquery(".parent").child().child(); But then blank because i havce to find unique class names

Comment: [Like so](https://jsfiddle.net/mfxh5yg1/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer**

If there are only 2 `div` elements that get repeated:

- Use a query that matches the `div` elements which indexes are greater than 1 `:gt(1)` under the `:first-child` of your `.parent` elements,
- Use the `.hide()` method.

```js
$('.parent > div:first-child > div:gt(1)').hide();
```

```css
.swatch-attribute.size {
  background: #faa;
}
.swatch-attribute.color {
  background: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="swatch-opt-115">
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also added the closing  to make it work correctly.

Hope it helps.

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

**Old answer**

Here is a solution to show only the first elements:

- Use of `.hide()` on all elements,
- Use `.show()` on the `.first()` elements,
- Plus, I added some colors and content to make the snippet more visual.

Snippet:

```js
$(".swatch-attribute.size").hide().first().show();
$(".swatch-attribute.color").hide().first().show();
```

```css
.swatch-attribute.size {
  background: #faa;
}
.swatch-attribute.color {
  background: #aaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="swatch-opt-115">
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I also added the closing `</div>` to make it work correctly.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But It is not confirmed that it will always be size, color, it can be anything so the logic needs to be on repeating elements.

Comment: @LAW There will always be only 2 elements that repeat? It will always be `div` elements?

Comment: parent will be the name of class. and the repeating elements will fall under the first child of parent class.

Comment: @LAW Did you correctly closed your `div` elements as I did?

Comment: The closing div was a typo from me, the html is actually forming using php code.

Comment: The earlier code was working with static class name, but this is not

Comment: Can you help me with code for just the first and second size, color show rest all hide

Comment: @LAW The snippet is working. If it is not working in your code, I suggest you try to spot the differences.

Answer (score 1):

> But It is not confirmed that the class names will always be the same. what is known is they will always be repeated.

This should work for you

```
var tempObj = {};
$(".parent > div > div").each(function() {
    var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
  //console.log(classes);
  tempObj[classes] = "";
});
//console.log(tempObj);

for(var key in tempObj) {
  $('.' + key +':gt(0)').hide();  
};
```

```js
var tempObj = {};
$(".parent > div > div").each(function() {
 var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').join('.');
  //console.log(classes);
  tempObj[classes] = "";
});
//console.log(tempObj);

for(var key in tempObj) {
  $('.' + key +':gt(0)').hide();  
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="swatch-opt-115">
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am checking

Comment: What exactly is not working, I could see only 2 divs, rest are hidden https://jsfiddle.net/ge413r8y/6/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ge413r8y/7/ I am using require to load jquery, so with require it is not working.

Comment: The code is working correctly, but unfortunately not working for me. Thanks for the time though.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works :)

```js
var first_class = $(".parent > div > div:nth-child(1)").attr("class").replace(" ", ".");
var second_class = $(".parent > div > div:nth-child(2)").attr("class").replace(" ", ".");

var first_class_count = $("."+first_class).length;
var second_class_count = $("."+second_class).length;

if(first_class_count > 1){
  $("."+first_class+":not(:first-child)").hide();
}

if(second_class_count > 1){
  $("."+second_class+":not(:nth-child(2))").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="swatch-opt-115">
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute size" attribute-code="size" attribute-id="141">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Size" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">size 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swatch-attribute color" attribute-code="color" attribute-id="93">
      <div aria-activedescendant="" tabindex="0" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" role="listbox" aria-label="Color" class="swatch-attribute-options clearfix">color 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use core JavaScript Concepts

```
document.getElementById('YourID').style.display="none";
```

Comment: did you actually read the question? These elements don't even have IDs, and anyway the idea is to hide several of them at once, so using an ID is not a good solution, for both those reasons.